# Databinding in Panel

Tags: javascript, data-binding, filter, sapui5

i want to bind my data to a panel with an ID in a fragment called Bids.

My View:

```
<ScrollContainer width="100%" height="75%" horizontal="true" vertical="true" focusable="false">
        <core:Fragment fragmentName="myApp.fragments.Details"   type="XML" />
        <core:Fragment type="XML" fragmentName="myApp.fragments.Bids" />            
</ScrollContainer>
```

My Fragment

```
<Panel width="auto" id="BidPanel">
  <l:Grid defaultSpan="XL6 L6 M12 S12" defaultIndent="XL0 L0 M3 S0" id="BidsGrid">
    <l:VerticalLayout>
        <l:HorizontalLayout>
            <Label text="Bid ID" class="myLabel" textAlign="Right" />
            <Text id="ReverseBidId" text="{Items>BidID}" />
        </l:HorizontalLayout>
    </l:VerticalLayout>
  </l:Grid>
</Panel>
```

This part of my JS binds the Datamodel named Items to my view and works fine.

```
oView.bindElement({
                path : "Items>/ItemDocumentSet(guid'" + oArgs.Doid + "')",
                events : {
                    change: this._onBindingChange.bind(this),
                    dataRequested: function (oEvent) {
                        oView.setBusy(true);
                    },
                    dataReceived: function (oEvent) {
                        oView.setBusy(false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

But i need another binding with an filter like

```
var filter = new Filter("BReftoaucDoid", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oArgs.Doid);
```

for my fragment part. I've no idea to do that.

This doesn't work:

```
oView.byId("BidPanel").bindElement({
                path : "Items>/BidDocumentSet",
                filters: [filter],
                events : {
                    change: this._onBindingChange.bind(this),
                    dataRequested: function (oEvent) {
                        oView.setBusy(true);
                    },
                    dataReceived: function (oEvent) {
                        oView.setBusy(false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: have you done this?: oView.addDependent(oFragment);

Comment: In my fragment the data from my first binding is present but my Problem is the binding of the Panel with other data from a new request. I've no idea how to do that.

Comment: I have Items with IDs. With this ID i'll do another request to fetch other data for this view

Comment: Can you share your JSON/oData Model structure?